# ASP.NET Core Web API: Why need ModelState validation in Get request?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

VS 2015 automatically generated the following code:

```
// GET: api/Companies/5
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetCompany([FromRoute] int id)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    Company company = await _context.Companies.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);

    if (company == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    return Ok(company);
}
```

What is the point of ModelState validation here?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you used the Web Api template. Since you didn't start from the "Empty" template, VS generated code, that the Microsoft team deemed "good practice".

The point is, that if you want a certain field to contain an email, another to be required, and so on, you might have marked them with data annotations. Now, there's an additional check for those before your method is executed (unnecessary for a simple int, but it's implied that you're likely going to change the arguments). Check [this](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/model-validation-in-aspnet-web-api) article for more information.

If you find these additions unnecessary, you can always start your project from the Empty template.